# How to get an element from a node in XDocument where two other elements are known

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, element, linq-to-xml

I'm stumped (again) with an misunderstanding of XDocument/Linq. For the XML below, I have `nameEn` and `provinceCode` as variables in my code. I'm trying to identify the `code` (e.g., `s0000002`) and `nameFr` given I have the other two elements. The `provinceCode` and `NameEn` combined are unique in the XML (no duplication).

```xml
<siteList>
  <site code="s0000001">
    <nameEn>Edmonton</nameEn>
    <nameFr>Edmonton</nameFr>
    <provinceCode>AB</provinceCode>
  </site>
  <site code="s0000002">
    <nameEn>Algonquin Park</nameEn>
    <nameFr>Parc Algonquin</nameFr>
    <provinceCode>ON</provinceCode>
  </site>
...
</siteList>
```

Here's the code I'm trying (my XML is in the "loaded" XDocument:

```
selectedProvince = "ON";
selectedCity = "Algonquin Park";      
strSiteCode = loaded.Descendants("site")
    .Where(x => x.Element("provinceCode").Value == selectedProvince)
    .Where(x => x.Element("nameEn").Value == selectedCity)
    .Select(x => x.Element("code").Value)
    .ToString();
strNameFR = loaded.Descendants("site")
    .Where(x => x.Element("provinceCode").Value == selectedProvince)
    .Where (x => x.Element("nameEn").Value == selectedCity)
    .Select(x => x.Element("nameFr").Value)
    .ToString();
```

The string `strSiteCode` returns: `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]`and`strNameFR`returns`""`.

I can't figure out what the working code should look like.  Thanks for any help.

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably rewrite it like this:

- get the list of matching `<site>` nodes once
- iterate over all matches (typically only one)
- get the `code` **attribute** and `nameFr` element from those matching items

Code would look like this:

```
// determine the matching list of <site> nodes ...
var selectedSites = loaded
                       .Descendants("site")
                       .Where(x => x.Element("provinceCode").Value == selectedProvince)
                       .Where(x => x.Element("nameEn").Value == selectedCity);

// iterate over all matching <site> nodes
foreach (var site in selectedSites)
{
    // grab the code attribute and nameFr element from <site> node
    var siteCode = site.Attribute("code").Value;
    var nameFR = site.Element("nameFr").Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up with much the same code I started with. What your code had that mine didn't was that you used "Attribute" instead of "Element". So that is why the code for strSiteCode wasn't working. (thank you!!) And my code for strNameFR was actually working, except I had accidentally made it ="" while testing. (Doh! Smacks forehead)

Comment: @Doug: a classical **PICNIC** : Problem In Chair - Not In Computer :-)

Comment: There's a few null ref problems that could arise using this code, btw. :)

Comment: @xixonia: yes, obviously - this was absolutely assuming that the "provinceCode" and "nameEn" on the <site> nodes are **always** there (and also the "code" attribute on <site> and the "nameFr" element inside that node) - for sure! I wasn't trying to show how to perfectly handle all potential errors ...

Comment: Righto. I just got excited, because the explicit operators on the XNode set of classes are really cool for things like this. Using '(string)x.Element(...)' is the same as 'x.Element(...).Value', except if the element comes up null, it'll just return null on the cast. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var result = loaded.Descendants("site")
    .Where(x => (x.Element("provinceCode").Value == selectedProvince) &&
                 (x.Element("nameEn").Value == selectedCity) )
    .Select(x => x.Element("code").Value)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    strSiteCode = result.ToString();
}
```

The `Select()` call returns a collection (which, in your case happens to have just one element). So you'll have to call `SingleOrDefault()` (or `Single()` ) to get the one item. Also, I removed the second `Where()` and included the condition to the first `Where()`.

Comment: Hi, Bala. I couldn't get this to work. I kept getting this error "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'" Thanks

Comment: @Doug Ah! I overlooked something when combining the two `Where()`s. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that it's possible that the "x.Element(...)" method will return null, whereby accessing "Value" on it will cause a null ref. This is assuming that your xml may not *always* have the provinceCode or nameEn. If it does, you won't have a problem, but you wouldn't want to put that possible null ref ex in release code, anyways. The following solves the null ref problem.

```
var site = loaded
    .Descendants("site")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("provinceCode") == selectedProvince &&
                    x => (string)x.Element("nameEn") == selectedCity);    

if (site == null)
{
    return
}

var siteCode = (string)site.Attribute("code");
var nameFr = (string)site.Element("nameFr");
```